# Selecting non existent columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here is my small example:

```
library(data.table)
data<-data.table(x_2dig_id=rnorm(100))
data$x_2dig
```

What I do not understand, why I do not get an error (i.e. there is no column x_2dig in my data).

This would be great if somebody could elaborate on this.

Comment: see manual of `$` about partial matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens with lists as well which is one of the very basic data structure type in R. $ is a shorthand operator, where x$y is equivalent to x[["y", exact = FALSE]]. It’s often used to access variables in a data frame.

If you want to receive a warning for partial matching then you can do :

```
options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)
```

From R documenation:

```
?`[[`
```

> x[[i, exact = TRUE]]
>
> exact  Controls possible partial matching of [[ when extracting by a
>   character vector (for most objects, but see under ‘Environments’). The
>   default is no partial matching. Value NA allows partial matching but
>   issues a warning when it occurs. Value FALSE allows partial matching
>   without any warning.

and

> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference
>   is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is
>   equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching
>   behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

This is also explained in Advanced R book of Hadley Wickham's subsetting chapter. You can find it [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Answer (score 0):

This goes back to the old days of R being overly helpful and trying to guess what you meant.  Data frames (upon which data tables are built) have this functionality, while tibbles (data_frame) intentionally leave this out to prevent the problem you're seeing!  Hadley talks about this sometimes in his talks.

Comment: thanks a lot any ideas on how to prevent something like this ?

Comment: Using data_frame instead of data.frame (using Hadley's tibble) is super helpful, and not just in eliminating the "here, I'll help you guess" problem.  Try, e.g., this:  `library(tidyverse)
data<-data_frame(x_2dig_id=rnorm(100))
data$x_2dig`

Answer (score 0):

Because data.table knows that you have gotten a unique identifier of the column. Example below demonstrates that once it isn't unique, it fails.

```
data<-data.table(x_2dig_id=rnorm(100),x_2dig_id2=rnorm(100))
data$x_2dig

NULL
```

Edit: Per Joy, this maybe an R thing, and not a data.table per se'.